# Objectify Query by list's element

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Objectify to create an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Collection {

    @Id
    private String name;
    @Index
    private List<Long> viewersIds;

//other fields
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the list of Collections which have a particular viewerId, lets say 1. I have tried:

```
List<Collection> usersCollections = ofy().load().type(Collection.class).filter("viewersIds",1).list();
```

and

```
ofy().load().type(Collection.class).filter("viewersIds =",1).list();
```

and

```
ofy().load().type(Collection.class).filter("viewersIds ==",1).list();
```

Getting all Collections works using:

```
ofy().load().type(Collection.class).list();
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Changing the Colllection object to contain a list of strings viewerIds instead of Long

```
@Index
private List<String> viewersIds;
```

And then query it with:

```
ofy().load().type(Collection.class).filter("viewerIds", value).list();
```

works. So this could be a solution if the list can be of Strings.

Comment: do you know any way if it's a list of objects?

Comment: Something like .filter("users.id IN", values), supposing you have a List of User objects called "users" and you want to filter by a property called id belonging to the User object.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is that viewerIds is indeed indexed in the entities that are supposed to be returned: https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query

Comment: Thank you for your reply! viewerIds is not indexed, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for 'in'

```
.filter("<collection> in", value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That call expects value to be a collection. But I am only looking for the collections that have a particular viewerId in their viewerIds list. Of course, a workaround would be to create a List<Long> values and add to this list one element: the viewerId. I have tried that and it works: ofy().load().type(Collection.class).filter("viewerIds in",values).list();  However, if I change the  private List<Long> viewersIds from the Collection object to  private List<String> viewersIds, I can call it with ofy().load().type(Collection.class).filter("viewerIds", value).list()